# Another planar separator ref question

Tags: reference-request, planar-graphs, separation

Do any of you know a reference for the following (surprisingly tedious to prove) result?

Given a connected planar graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $n+t$ edges, it has a vertex separator of size $O( \sqrt{t}+1)$.

Comment: Is it really that tedious? You have at most $t$ blocks, contract them into vertices and use the weighted separator theorem for them. In case the separating blocks are large, you can keep destroy all $O(\sqrt t)$ edges among them and then separate each arbitrarily with two vertices each.

Comment: What is the exact definition of the blocks?

Comment: I think you mean a balanced vertex separator as otherwise a planar graph has a bounded degeneracy.

Comment: Do you really need the $+1$ inside the $O(\cdot)$?

Comment: Yes. If t is zero....

Comment: @domotorp BTW, I dont think your idea works - the whole graph might be a single block - just think about a path, and an additional edge connecting the two endpoints, and them some other t edges...

Comment: Yeah, that is quite convincing.

Comment: Okay, I've managed to recall what I had in mind. I didn't mean blocks, but faces. The number of faces is exactly $t+1$, so you can use the separator theorem for the dual graph. And then I agree that there are some tedious details, but probably not that bad.

Comment: Yeh. I dont think this works either - although that is *definitely* the first thing to try. The problem is that your separator might include a face that is adjacent to many faces. Implementing its separation in the primal is going to be expensive. Also, it is not clear how to maintain the prices/number of the vertices in the primal in this process (but this is probably doable).

Comment: You may assume wlog that the graph is vertex $3$-connected (no separation of order $\leq 2$). In such graphs the minimum degree is $3$, and so the number of vertices is $O(t)$. Lipton-Tarjan then gives the bound.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a proof using a well-known hammer.

Let us assume wlog that $G$ is connected, hence it is a spanning tree plus $t+1$ edges. Clearly any cycle in $G$ must contain one of these $t+1$ edges which are part of the spanning tree.

I claim that the treewidth of $G$ is $O(\sqrt{t})$ which would imply the desired separator (and some more). To prove the claim let $k$ be the treewidth of $G$. Then by a theorem of Robertson-Seymour-Thomas, since $G$ is planar, there is a grid minor of size $\Omega(k)$. However a grid minor of size $\Omega(k)$ has $\Omega(k^2)$ disjoint cycles and each of them requires one of the $t+1$ edges. Hence $k = O(\sqrt{t})$.

Comment: The above argument is a special case of the fact that if the feedback vertex set size of a planar graph $G$ is $t$ then treewidth of $G$ is $O(\sqrt{t})$. This is well-known in FPT literature so overall the argument is standard.

Comment: The quoted theorem of Robertson Seymour Thomas has a relatively short self contained proof, so it is not *such* a big hammer.

Comment: Edited to remove "big" but retained "hammer".

Comment: @daniello isn't that graph minor V?